# How to set an array as a parameter for a constructor?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm doing an assignment for my class and this is my code.

```java
public class Realty1 {
    Realty1 realty = new Realty1(incomeandCost[]);

    Realty1[] incomeAndCost = {
        new Realty1( 10000,  25000), new Realty1(35000,  100000), 
        new Realty1( 67000, 125000), new Realty1(89000,  199000), 
        new Realty1(105000, 250000), new Realty1(51000, 1025000)
    };
}
```

I'm just confused and not really sure how to accomplish this. I added the array as a parameter, because without it there the code doesn't work, but now I'm getting a ".class expected" error.

Comment: For the intend of parameters, an array is just a normal object. If we wanted, for example, write a method `foo` that takes a `String`-array as parameter, we would write it like that: `void foo(String[] bar) { ... }`

Comment: Assuming you have `public Realty1(Realty1[] a) { ... }` then you can do `Realty1 realty = new Realty1(incomeAndCost);` (no brackets needed since you're passing a reference) given there is a `Realty1[]` initialised beforehand (which means you will have to swap the two lines). Note that you are doing it inside the class body, normally we write a method which would initialise/prepare objects. Also beware of typos like `incomeandCost` and `Realty`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? What does `Realty1` represent? Does it really make sense for `Realty1` to hold an array of `Realty1` objects? This kind of recursion is sometimes useful, but doesn't seem so in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that actually two classes are needed here:

- With two integer fields, constructed as `Realty(int x, int y)`
- With `Realty[]` array field, constructed as `Realty1(Realty[] arr)`

Example:

```java
public class Realty {
    private int x, y;

    public Realty(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

```java
public class Realty1 {
    private Realty[] incomeAndCost;

    public Realty1(Realty[] incomeAndCost) {
        this.incomeAndCost = incomeAndCost; 
    }

    public Realty1() { // default no-args constructor
        this(new Realty[] {
            new Realty( 10_000,  25_000), new Realty(35_000,  100_000), 
            new Realty( 67_000, 125_000), new Realty(89_000,  199_000), 
            new Realty(105_000, 250_000), new Realty(51_000, 1025_000)
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with your assessment that what the OP is trying to do likely requires two different classes. In addition, `Realty1` needs a more meaningful name. Not saying you should do it here since we don't have enough information, but just wanted to point this out for the OP and future readers.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, separation of the two classes is mandatory because after fixing the typos, the OP is going to encounter a `StackOverflowError`

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Realty1 {
  int A;
  int B;
  Realty1 realty = new Realty1(incomeandCost[]);
  public Realty1(int A, int B){
     this.A = A;
     this.B = B;
  }
  Realty1[] incomeAndCost = {
     new Realty1( 10000,  25000), new Realty1(35000,  100000), 
     new Realty1( 67000, 125000), new Realty1(89000,  199000), 
     new Realty1(105000, 250000), new Realty1(51000, 1025000)
  };
}
```

Comment: This is likely to result in endless loop and `StackOverflowError` - when creating an instance of `Realty1`, an array `incomeAndCost` is created and _populated_ too with new instances of `Realty1`... Also, the same typos copied from the OP's question, and constructor accepting an array is missing..